# How To Hide Rows If Cell Is Blank In Excel? And add new row below

Tags: excel, vba

1. I have created table A1: J4, where I add data to rows 2, 3 and 4.
2. I want to hide rows 3 and 4 via a macro if there is no data in it.
3. Then a new clean row "insert row" is automatically added under row 10. If I hid row 3, one is added, if I hid row 4, two new rows are added under row 10.
   Maybe you'll understand.

This code below can check if the values are in a row and if they are not, then it will hide the row.
However, I would need two rows to be hidden and at the same time create two new ones under row 10.

**Code:**

```
Sub HideRows()
Range("A3").Select
Do While ActiveCell.Row < 6
If ActiveCell.Value = "" And ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Value = "" Then
Selection.EntireRow.Hidden = True
End If
ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
Cells.EntireColumn.Hidden = False
Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: I think you are confusing Columns with Rows, and it is unclear if when you say "Line" if you mean row. Rows are the [1,2,3,...] Columns are the [A,B,C,...]. Can you clarify this in your question?

Comment: Thanks for warning. Sorry. I mean the rows..

Comment: By default, I can hide a row if there is no data in it. If I enter a number, for example 1234, then after pressing the "hide" button, it will hide the line in which the numbers are 1234.
Maybe it's clearer.